# Nothing to show in android xml preview design in android studio

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

nothing is showing in android xml preview when i use [BottomBar library](https://github.com/roughike/BottomBar)

The image indicates my problem
[image]

**Android studio 2.2.3**

Comment: Did you try to press `Synchronize` button in the upper left corner?

Comment: Yes and  problem is not resolved

Comment: is it showing after removing the **BottmBar** view form the xml

Comment: Yes,
But I want to do with BottomBar!
what to do ?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. (Rendering problem on preview)

So, I tried many methods.

1. Android Studio > File > Invalidate Caches and Restart.
2. Remove ".android" file in Home Directory. And restart.

and etc...

But all of the solutions are not resolved.

So, I just uninstall Android Studio and re-download, reinstall.

Finally, I've solved this problem.